# Label Not Making Space in Table Cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

So I am having a problem with a label in a table cell not making room for itself and instead somehow being behind it's sibling, but taking up space INSIDE of it's sibling?

I've created a JSFiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/8yzLP/

There's a label that inside a div that's inside a table cell but it's being hidden by it's sibling div.

Here's the structure markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="trip-finder-table-cell">
            <div class="trip-finder-sort-by-container">
                <label>Sort By</label>
                <div class="selectList_container trip-finder-sort-by-select" tabindex="0" style="position: relative;">
                    <p class="selectList_value">
                        <span class="selectValue_content" style="cursor: pointer; display: block; text-align: left;">Sort Option</span>
                        <span class="select-carat" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is a coming from all over, but I've included the necessary elements to recreate the problem in the JS fiddle.  They are as follows:

```
td.trip-finder-table-cell {
width: 17%;
padding: 15px 1.25%;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
}

td.trip-finder-table-cell > div[class*=trip-finder] {
position: relative;
}

td.trip-finder-table-cell > div > label:not([for]) {
display: inline;
float: left;
line-height: 30px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.selectList_value {
padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
width: 100%;
}

.select-carat {
display: block;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
float: right;
right: 3px;
top: 2px;
background: transparent url('../img/global/forms/select-carat.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.selectList_options {
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 250px;
overflow-y: auto;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
background: #fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.selectList_container {
min-width: 110px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
background: #fcfcfc;
position: relative;
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work as expected (with the label to the left, and the sibling to the right), but no matter what I try it just doesn't happen.  Maybe someone can be kind enough to help me out?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8yzLP/2/
Generally anytime you `float` something everything else around it must also be floated or it will be layered over

Answer (score 0):

Your floating some elements and some are not
check ur position: xxx and float: xxx lines

mainly these lines should go

```
.select-carat {
position: absolute;
float: right;
right: 3px;
top: 2px;
}

td.trip-finder-table-cell > div > label:not([for]) {float: left;}
```